# Как получить направление в 3d пространстве?

Tags: c#, геометрия

Есть в 3d мире машина.
И мне надо как то получать ее заднею часть.
То есть по повороту машины как то определить направление куда она смотрит и получить точку сзади этого автомобиля.
Что то типу того как в Unity есть `transform.forward`
Но так как это делается не на Unity тут нету данной штуки.
Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: А что есть? На чем делается? Как у вас задается автомобиль?

Comment: Это мод для игры. По сути мне надо проверить стоит ли игрок сзади автомобиля.
Функциями игры этого не сделать.
Все что могу узнать о этом автомобиле это позиция и поворот.
И мне надо как то получить позицию сзади автомобиля по его повороту и позиции.

Comment: Позиция в координатах x,y,z и поворот в углах a,b,c? Или как?

Comment: Да. Позиция float x y z а поворот так же поворот float a b c.
Тут не Кватерионы (или как их там)...
Которые в Unity используются.

Comment: Вам нужно точно узнать, что представляют из себя a,b,c. Это могут быть либо координаты вектора, либо углы. Если это углы, то вы увидите значения в диапазоне 0-6.28 или -3.14 - +3.14. В любом случае вам придется высчитать эти же значения для пары точек авто-человек и сравнить полученные a,b,c с a,b,c авто. Остается вопрос как именно высчитать, а это зависит от того, что у вас там хранится.

Comment: Это углы от 0 до 360... И я просто не знаю как расчитать где перед...
[ссылка](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sbc49.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Вычислите углы вектора игрок-автомобиль по этим формулам:

```
//x_a, y_a, z_a - координаты автомобиля
//x_m, y_m, z_m - координаты игрока

var dx = x_a - x_m;
var dy = y_a - y_m;
var dz = z_a - z_m;
var length = Math.Sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy + dz * dz);
var a = Math.Acos(dx/length) * 180 / Math.PI;
var b = Math.Acos(dy/length) * 180 / Math.PI;
var c = Math.Acos(dz/length) * 180 / Math.PI;
```

Теперь сравните их с углами направления движения авто:

```
//m_a, m_b, m_c - направление движения авто
//eps - допустимое отклонение
if (Math.Abs(m_a - a) < eps && Math.Abs(m_b - b) < eps && ath.Abs(m_c - c) < eps)
{
    //точка за авто
}
```